# Does too many projects in a solution slow down Visual Studio performance?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

Would it be better to have 10 large projects in a solution or 100 smaller projects in a solution in terms of Visual Studio performance?

This is a hypothetical question where I'm disregarding dependency issues and over solution architecture.

This is dealing primarily with C# projects.

Answer (score -1):

The choice of how many projects you will create depends on the architecture yo use, it don't affect the performance of VS. If you are working with services is a good practice to make many projects to desagregate the solution, and later be able to deploy them into different servers to emprove the performance of your application.

Comment: I get why one might want more or less projects from a services or architecture point of view, however I was asking strictly in terms of Visual Studio performance.

Comment: It does affect VS performance - it increases build and load times at least.